# Instantiate DBContext and get its metadata from a Type (another project)

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I have **Project 1** which is an ASP.NET Core application and **Project 2** which is a .NET Standard library.

Is there a way to instantiate a DbContext found in **Project 1** from my library using only the Type? I only want to get the metadata about it.

How does Scaffolding do it?

**Example**

```
var context = InstatiateFromType(typeof(MyContext));
// So that I get access to the metadata
var x = context.Model.FindEntityType(...);
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understood correctly.

But instead of instantiating it yourself, you could use get an instance via DI in your constructor.

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddMvc();
    services.AddDbContext<MyContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer("connectionString"));
}
```

And then in your Class you just get it via the constructor.

Comment: There is no DI in the library.

Comment: You could use the Activator to create an instance

Comment: That's what I'm doing now, but I'm wondering if there is a better way as the Activator needs the DbContext to be configured with an actual database.

Comment: Ah okay. I'm sorry, but I ran out of suggestions for now.